# F# style - prefer () or <|

Tags: f#, coding-style

Which of theese two alternatives do you find yourself using most often, and which is more "idiomatic"?

1. f arg (obj.DoStuff())
2. f arg <| obj.DoStuff()

Comment: +1 cause I didn't even know `<|` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, I don't know that one or the other is more idiomatic.

Personally, the only time I use <| is with "raise":

```
raise <| new FooException("blah")
```

Apart from that, I always use parens.  Note that since most F# code uses curried functions, this does not typically imply any "extra" parens:

```
f arg (g x y)
```

It's when you get into non-curried functions and constructors and whatnot that it starts getting less pretty:

```
f arg (g(x,y))
```

We will probably at least *consider* changing the F# languages rules so that high-precedence applications bind even more tightly; right now

```
f g()
```

parses like

```
f g ()
```

but a lot of people would like it to parse as

```
f (g())
```

(the motivating case in the original question).  If you have a strong opinion about this, leave a comment on this response.

Comment: After reading this and the following threads on FSHub
http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/3665.aspx
http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/5421.aspx
I'm signing the "make f g() parse like f (g())" petition as soon as I can find a pen! 
"Fixing" this would make utilizing the framework so much prettier.

Comment: I would also like to see f g() parse like f (g()) to make using method calls from the framework more natural.  But, I'm worried it's too late now, considering we already have production release...

Comment: It actually is still possible to change; the language differentiates between 'application' (`g x`) and 'high precedence application' (`g(x)` with no space between the `g` and the open-paren), and so `f g(x)` never compiles today, regardless of whether `f` takes 1 or 2 curried arguments (`f g (x)` passes 2 args to `f`, and `f (g(x))` passes one arg to `f`).  So it's possible for a future revision of the language to 'admit more legal programs' as a non-breaking change.  But it would be awfully subtle (making the whitespace meaningful to differential legal programs) and so is unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Because type inference works from left to right, a bonus of using `|>` is that it allows F# to infer the type of the argument of the function.

As a contrived example,

```
[1; 2; 3] |> (fun x -> x.Length*2)
```

works just fine, but

```
(fun x -> x.Length*2) [1; 2; 3]
```

complains of "lookup on object of indeterminate type".

Answer (score 0):

I use () much much more often, but thats just preference, I'm pretty sure that <| is more idomatic, but I use () by habit.

Comment: Rayne, I started to grok F# recently. Do you use it for commercial development or just for fun? I'm very interested in real-world F# apps

Comment: Just for fun right now, but it's very well suited for real world apps, this language is beautiful. It can be used pretty much to the same extent C# can only more consise elegant, and readable code!

Comment: Rayne, agree. I really like it. I hope they will get us RTM version soon.

Comment: I use it to automate performance tests and write utilities and scripts at work. Hopefully it will gain traction.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, I much prefer |> because it reads from left to right.